# Not getting correct value of BehaviorSubject unless I do a page refresh

Tags: angular, partial-page-refresh, behaviorsubject

I'm having trouble with my BehaviorSubject not pushing its new value to my observers. I follewed this tutorial https://netbasal.com/angular-2-persist-your-login-status-with-behaviorsubject-45da9ec43243 but no luck there. I also tried to find something on SO and dr. Google, but no luck there either.
I have no clue to what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code for my Authservice and components that interact with it.

**Authenticationservice**

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  private _url = '/api';
  private _user$: BehaviorSubject<string>;
  private _isLoggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

  public redirectUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    this._user$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(currentUser && currentUser.email);
    this._isLoggedIn  = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.hasUser());
  }

  get user$(): BehaviorSubject<string> {
    return this._user$;
  }

  isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._isLoggedIn.asObservable();
  }

  hasUser() {
    return !!localStorage.getItem('currentUser')
  }

  get token(): string {
    const localCurrentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    return !!localCurrentUser ? localCurrentUser.token  : '';
  }

  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post(`${this._url}/login`, { email: email, password: password })
      .map(res => res.json()).map(res => {
        const token = res.token;
        if (token) {
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ email: email, token: token }));
          this._user$.next(email);
          this._isLoggedIn.next(true);
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
  }

  logout() {
    if (this.user$.getValue()) {
      localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
      setTimeout(() => this._user$.next(null));
      this._isLoggedIn.next(false)
    }
  }

  register(email: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post(`${this._url}/register`, { email: email, password: password })
      .map(res => res.json()).map(res => {
        const token = res.token;
        if (token) {
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ email: email, token: res.token }));
          this._user$.next(email);  
          this._isLoggedIn.next(true)    
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
  }
}
```

**nav.component.ts**

```
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../user/authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css'],
  providers: [AuthenticationService]
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  private _isLoggedIn: Observable<boolean>

  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService) {
      this._isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn();
  }

  ngOnInit() { 
  }

  get isLoggedIn() {
    return this._isLoggedIn
  }

}
```

**nav.component.html** only the problem code*

```
<li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!(isLoggedIn | async)"><a class="nav-link" href="#"
      routerLink="/login">Login</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!(isLoggedIn | async)"><a class="nav-link" href="#"
      routerLink="/register">Register</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="(isLoggedIn | async)"><a class="nav-link" href="#"
      routerLink="/logout">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
```

navcomponent is part of app module and authservice is part of user module

**user.module.ts**

```
import { AuthGuardService } from './auth-guard.service';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from './logout/logout.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';


const userRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(userRoutes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    LogoutComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthenticationService,
    AuthGuardService
  ]
})
export class UserModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {NavComponent} from './nav/nav.component';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing/app-routing.module';
import {NavdropdownDirective} from './nav/navdropdown.directive';
import {PageNotFoundComponent} from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import {RegistrationModule} from './registration/registrations.module';
import {ScheduleModule} from './schedule/schedule.module';
import {PreferencesModule} from './preferences/preferences.module';
import {UserModule} from './user/user.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent,
    NavdropdownDirective,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    BrowserModule,
    UserModule,
    RegistrationModule,
    ScheduleModule,
    PreferencesModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I hope someone can help me out with what I'm doing wrong.

> Help me Obi-one Kenobi, you're my only hope - Princess Lea, A new hope

Comment: Does "AppRoutingModule" use lazy loaded routes?

Comment: No, i have no lazy loaded routes in my app

Answer (score 1):

When you return an Observable like in this code:

```
  isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._isLoggedIn.asObservable();
  }
```

The calling code needs to subscribe.

```
  ngOnInit() { 
    this.auth.isLoggedIn().subscribe(value => this._isLoggedIn = value);
  }
```

For what you are doing, using a BehaviorSubject is a bit overkill. Since isLoggedIn is bound in the UI, it will automatically handle change notifications. All you really need is a simple boolean property:

**Auth Service**

```
this.isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
```

**Nav Component**

```
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() { 
  }

  get isLoggedIn() {
    return this.auth.isLoggedIn;
  }

}
```

Any time the `isLoggedIn` state changes in the service, the change detection will pick up the change and the UI will adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately none of these solutions did the trick for me. I indeed forgot to subscribe to the observable. Totally missed that. But still I need to refresh my page manually to see the variable change. I'm really confused. Could it be that it has something to do with my module imports?